# Rails Assigning a class in html erb works in one place, doesn't work in another

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view where I make 2 loops to output the information. One as a menu and another as data:

```
<div class="base-form side-menu">
    <ul class="food-groups">
      <% @food_categories.each do |category| %>
        <li class="<%= "#{Food::CATEGORIES[category]}"%>" data-content=".<%= "#{Food::CATEGORIES[category]}-content"%>">  <%="#{category}"%>  </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="base-form main-form">

    <% @food_categories.each do |cat| %>
      <%= "#{Food::CATEGORIES[cat]}-content" %>
        <div class="<%= "#{Food::CATEGORIES[cat]}-content"%>">

          <% @foods.where(category: "#{Food::CATEGORIES[cat]}").find_each do |food| %>
            <p>
              <%= "Name: #{food.name}, portion: #{food.portion}, calories: #{food.calories}" %>
            </p>

          <% end %>

        </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>
```

First loop works fine, each element gets its class correctly. Second loop(with |cat|) works, but the div's don't get any classes assigned. I even copied the class="<%=...%>" to the 't' from the first loop and it still doesn't work! Although just putting the string on the page that I'm also passing as a class works fine. I don't get it!

Comment: Does this line: `<%= "#{Food::CATEGORIES[cat]}-content" %>` works ?

Comment: Yes it does. Now I deleted spaces before and after <%= and %> and it magically started working(even though I also had spaces in the first class assignment in li), BUT when I do "
$(".foods-content .main-form div").click(function() {

  alert($(this).classList);

});" it alerts undefined and I can't access the div in javascript...

Comment: Is your JS code is inside `.ready()` function?

Comment: I don't see any class named `.foods-content`

Comment: Yes it is, and there's .food-content, it just didn't get in the snippet. Doing it with or without document ready gave the same result.. Also I want to give class "active" to the first li and when I try to put this: "$(".Dairy").addClass('active');" in the beginning of my code it does nothing, although li on click changes class to active with 'this' keyword... what is this sorcery?

Comment: It would really help if you could add complete JS and html code for the page here.